# Flex-Air mobile TextInput cursor starts in the middle of a TextField on iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air, textinput

I am developing an Air Application for mobile Devices.
During the registration process we have some TextInput Fields.

On all devices everthing works fine but on iOs the cursor and the input text is placed somewhere in the middle of the TextInput - I think at the point the user clicks into the field...

Can I avoid this behaviour?

Thanks,

Christian

Seems the TextInputSkin makes the problem...

```
s|TextInput
{
    skinClass:        ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin");
    contentBackgroundColor: #807F7F;
    color:          #FFFFFF;
    fontSize:       32;
    fontFamily:     GGStandardFont;
    fontWeight:     normal;
}
```

Comment: With TextArea (and "spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin") everything works fine ... any suggestion why?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue which seemed to stem from using a custom font for the TextInput.

Setting the font family to a websafe font (ie Arial) when editing the TextInput helped. Then reset the font afterwards.

eg. (in flex)

```
softKeyboardActivating="setStyle('fontFamily', 'Arial')"
softKeyboardDeactivating="setStyle('fontFamily', 'MyCustomFont')"
```